# Postgres processes suddenly stop after high CPU?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I'm running a Postgres DB with a Node.js web application on a Ubuntu droplet with 16 vCPUs, and have found a strange behavior during times of high load for Postgres processes. It seems that Postgres processes stop completely following a time with near 100% CPU load, causing my API to freeze. Why is this?

Beneath attached are 2 screenshots that are approximately 1 minute apart from each other, using `top` in the command line.

**Starting web app through PM2** — https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs6WW.png

**After a while** — https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTc9G.png

**Finally** — https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVY10.png

I'm finding this behavior only when my server is handling 10,000+ requests per 10 minutes. Is this intended? What's going on here and is it possible to somehow not have these processes "stop" and not respawn unless I restart my Node.js app?

UPDATE: Postgres log file shows a lot of `unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction`. Is this caused by CPU overload or errors within the transaction?

Comment: In Linux top, you can toggle on the long form of the process titles by hitting 'c'.  This will offer much more information.  Also, it is best to best text as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Please don't post text only information as (hard to read) screen shots. Copy & Paste the text instead.

Comment: Do you have any error messages in the Postgres logfile?

Comment: @jjanes Oh, I see, sorry about that! I have added the links to the images if that helps. Will bear that in mind. And as for the -c flag, thanks — it's a lot better to see what's going on!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have now updated the question with what I can see in the logfile.

Comment: This needs detailed analysis. With three screenshots, nobody can guess whet is going on.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Do you have any suggestions as to what I can do to analyze this further?